# VLC Web Plugin and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrote an jQuery script for my VLC Plugin, that will hold the link from JSON formated code and past it in the plugin for the rtsp link.
But I have a problem.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/stream",
    processData: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
        stream = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            var vlc = vlcEmb;
            var link = stream.rtsp;
            var rtsp = link;
            vlc.playlist.clear();
            vlc.playlist.add(rtsp);
            vlc.playlist.play();
    }
});
```

here the code, Mozilla Firefox Firebug show me:

uncaught exception: No such method or arguments mismatch.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please show at which line?

Comment: I cant show the line... because the Firebug, dont say it to me xD